# How to apply a function to the active enum member like C++'s std::visit?

Tags: rust

I have a serialization library in C++ which serializes types into buffers for transmitting over network and to disk and I want to port it to Rust. The library supports serializing `std::variant` types that contain serializable types using the index and `std::visit` which can be used with a template lambda to serialize the active member in the variant:

```cpp
template<Serializable ... Object>
void serialize_variant(const std::variant<Object...>& var) {
    serialize_number(var.index());
    std::visit([](const auto& item) { serialize_object(item); }, var);
}
```

Rust has `match` which is useful when I know the enum's type but I can't match on an arbitrary enum. I also can't get the index of the member of an enum to serialize it before the item.

I have something like this incorrect code:

```rust
trait Serilizable {
    fn write_to_buffer(&self, buff: &[u8]) {}
}

impl Serilizable for i32 {
    /* implement serilization */
}
impl Serilizable for f64 {
    /* implement serilization */
}
impl Serilizable for String {
    /* implement serilization */
}

enum ToSerialize {
    I32(i32),
    F64(f64),
    Str(String),
}

fn serialize_object(obj: &Serilizable, buff: &[u8]) {
    obj.write_to_buffer(buff);
}

fn serialize_manually(var: &ToSerialize, buff: &[u8]) {
    match ToSerialize {
        I32(i) => {
            serialize_object(&0, buff);
            serialize_object(i, buff);
        }
        F64(f) => {
            serialize_object(&1, buff);
            serialize_object(i, buff);
        }
        Str(s) => {
            serialize_object(&2, buff);
            serialize_object(s, buff);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to replace `serialize_manually` with a generic function that accepts any enum of `Serializable` types and does something similar.

Comment: Your'e probably looking for [serde](https://serde.rs/).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I doubt it, the OP probably wants the bytes on the wire to be compatible between the two versions.

Comment: So you have listed things you cannot do.  What is the actual, practical, business case problem here?  Are you trying to (a) be compatible with C++ serialization/deserialization, or (b) mimic the pattern in rust code, but exact binary compatibility isn't a concern, (c) something else?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I want binary compatibility between c++ and rust and this is not the subject of this question. I asked to know how to have a generic function to serialize enum instead of doing match by hand every time.

Comment: Do you have any Rust code you've tried? You say you "can't match on an arbitrary enum", but it's not clear what you mean. It seems `std::variant` in C++ is an "anonymous" enum type, unlike Rust `enum`s. So it's not apples to apples.

Comment: Rust isn't as "loosey goosey" as C++. You need to guarantee that the type being passed in is (de)serializable, which means you'll need to implement a trait on it. The trait is usually implemented through a procedural / derive macro (again, see how [serde](https://serde.rs/) does it). Contrast to C++ where you write a bunch of code that may or may not work based on how it is called.

Comment: @Shepmaster in the c++ implementation I use concepts to ensure it works

Comment: I haven't had the opportunity to use C++'s concepts yet, but I understand they are close to traits. However, if C++ allows you to ensure that a concept applies to any arbitrary enum, then there's no equivalent in Rust. You'll need to opt-in to your (de)serialization for each concrete type.

Comment: I think your best bet is essentially what you have there. If you want to make it less verbose, you can use a declarative `macro_rules` macro.